# Get values from dataframe with MultiIndex index containg NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I cannot access the values of an index position that has a `nan` in it and wonder how I could solve this. (In my project this index has a very special meaning and I really need to keep it, otherwise I would need to make some dirty manual modifications: "there is always a solution" even if it is a very bad one).

```
df
Out
temp_playlist  objId
0              o1           [0, 6]
               o2           [1, 4]
               o3           [2, 5]
               o4       [8, 9, 12]
               o5         [10, 13]
               o6         [11, 14]
               NaN          [3, 7]
Name: x, dtype: object

df.index
Out
MultiIndex([(0, 'o1'),
            (0, 'o2'),
            (0, 'o3'),
            (0, 'o4'),
            (0, 'o5'),
            (0, 'o6'),
            (0,  nan)],
           names=['temp_playlist', 'objId'])
```

Now I want to access the `[3, 7]` values as `df.loc[(0, np.nan)]` and obtain the `KeyError: (0, nan)` error.

Just to put it in perspective: `[df.loc[idx] for idx in df.index if not pd.isna(idx[1])]` works properly because I am skipping the problematic index.

What am I missing and how could I solve this?

(Windows 10, python 3.8.5, pandas 1.3.1, numpy 1.20.3, reported to pandas [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43814))

Comment: One idea - is possible test if working with `None` ?

Comment: I tried to create the index manually as `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['o1', 'o2', 'o3', 'o4', 'o5', 'o6', None]], names=('temp_playlist', 'objId'))` and the `None` gets converted into `np.nan`. The result is the same exact index as posted in the question.

Comment: ya, unfortunately.

Comment: also failed `df.loc[(0, 'nan')]` ?

Comment: Yes, also with `KeyError`, but this one is clear, but that gave me an idea. Now this idea is a "bad solution", but it would be: `df.index = [str(idx) for idx in df.index]; df.loc['(0, nan)']`. I am not going to post this "solution" as an answer I am not going to accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I am able to reproduce your error after grouping and aggregating a data frame.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({
...     "temp_playlist": [0] * 15,
...     "objId": ['o1'] * 2 + ['o2'] * 2 + ['o3'] * 2 + ['o4'] * 3 + ['o5'] * 2 + ['o6'] * 2 + [pd.NA] * 2,
...     "vals": [0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 5, 8, 9, 12, 10, 13, 11, 14, 3, 7]
... })
>>> df = data.groupby(["temp_playlist", "objId"], dropna=False).agg(list)
>>> df.loc[(0, pd.NA)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/so-pandas-nan-index/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: <NA>
```

Passing in an explit MultiIndex works, though.

```
>>> df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0, pd.NA)], names=["temp_playlist", "objId"])]
                       vals
temp_playlist objId
0             NaN    [3, 7]

>>> df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0, pd.NA)])]
         vals
0 NaN  [3, 7]
```

And so does returning a data frame using a single tuple. Note using `[[]]` returns a DataFrame.

```
>>> df.loc[[(0, pd.NA)]]
                       vals
temp_playlist objId
0             NaN    [3, 7]
```

As does [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) (see also the [user guide on reindexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#reindexing-and-altering-labels)).

```
>>> df.reindex([(0, pd.NA)])
                       vals
temp_playlist objId
0             NaN    [3, 7]
```

### Original Attempt to Reproduce Error

I am not able to reproduce your error. You can see below that using `df.loc[(0, np.nan)]` works.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> nan_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0, 'o1'),
            (0, 'o2'),
            (0, 'o3'),
            (0, 'o4'),
            (0, 'o5'),
            (0, 'o6'),
            (0,  np.nan)])
>>> print(nan_index)
MultiIndex([(0, 'o1'),
            (0, 'o2'),
            (0, 'o3'),
            (0, 'o4'),
            (0, 'o5'),
            (0, 'o6'),
            (0,  nan)],
           )
>>> rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
>>> vals = [rng.choice(20, 2) for i in range(nan_index.shape[0])]
>>> print(vals)
[array([ 1, 15]), array([13,  8]), array([ 8, 17]), array([ 1, 13]), array([4, 1]), array([10, 19]), array([14, 15])]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"vals": vals}, index=nan_index)
>>> print(df)
           vals
0 o1    [1, 15]
  o2    [13, 8]
  o3    [8, 17]
  o4    [1, 13]
  o5     [4, 1]
  o6   [10, 19]
  NaN  [14, 15]
>>> print(df.loc[(0, 'o1')])
vals    [1, 15]
Name: (0, o1), dtype: object
>>> print(df.loc[(0, np.nan)])
vals    [14, 15]
Name: (0, nan), dtype: object
>>> print(pd.__version__)
1.3.1
```

Then I noticed that your index was printed as `(0, nan)` but mine was `(0, np.nan)`. The difference was that I used `np.nan` and I suspect yours is `pd.NA`.

```
>>> nan_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0, 'o1'),
            (0, 'o2'),
            (0, 'o3'),
            (0, 'o4'),
            (0, 'o5'),
            (0, 'o6'),
            (0,  pd.NA)])
>>> nan_index
MultiIndex([(0, 'o1'),
            (0, 'o2'),
            (0, 'o3'),
            (0, 'o4'),
            (0, 'o5'),
            (0, 'o6'),
            (0,  nan)],
           )
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"vals": vals}, index=nan_index)
>>> df
           vals
0 o1    [1, 15]
  o2    [13, 8]
  o3    [8, 17]
  o4    [1, 13]
  o5     [4, 1]
  o6   [10, 19]
  NaN  [14, 15]
```

However, that did not resolve the difference. I was still able to use `df.loc[(0, np.nan)]`.

```
>>> df.loc[(0, pd.NA)]
vals    [14, 15]
Name: (0, nan), dtype: object

>>> df.loc[(0, np.nan)]
vals    [14, 15]
Name: (0, nan), dtype: object
```

Moreover, I was also able to use `df.loc[(0, None)]`.

```
>>> df.loc[(0, None)]
vals    [14, 15]
Name: (0, nan), dtype: object
```

Just to confirm, `np.nan`, `pd.NA`, and `None` are all different objects. Pandas must treat them the same when used with `DataFrame.loc`.

```
>>> pd.NA is np.nan
False

>>> pd.NA is None
False

>>> np.nan is None
False

>>> type(pd.NA)
<class 'pandas._libs.missing.NAType'>

>>> type(np.nan)
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: `[...] Passing in an explit MultiIndex works, though [...]` very interesting. Tks, this seems more like a "better solution" than mine and that from @jezrael.

Comment: Still it looks like a bug. I mean, why would then `df.loc[[(0, <any pd compatible NaN variation>]]` work and actually return a list of the data at that index (eg [[3, 7]])?

Answer (score 1):

Idea with replace `NaN` to `NA`:

```
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0, 'o1'),
            (0, 'o2'),
            (0, 'o3'),
            (0, 'o4'),
            (0, 'o5'),
            (0, 'o6'),
            (0,  np.nan)])

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':0}, index=i)

df = df.rename(lambda x: 'NA' if pd.isna(x) else x, level=1)
print (df)
      a
0 o1  0
  o2  0
  o3  0
  o4  0
  o5  0
  o6  0
  NA  0

df.loc[(0, 'NA')]
```

Comment: Tks for the answer, but this is somehow similar to my answer. I will wait a couple of days, if nobody has another solution I will put this as a bug to the pandas git.

Answer (score 0):

One "bad solution", that is not really solving the underlying issue but provide a working solution, would be by converting the indices to strings (the `str` constructor is capable of amazing results here).

```
df.index = [str(idx) for idx in df.index]
df
Out 
(0, 'o1')        [0, 6]
(0, 'o2')        [1, 4]
(0, 'o3')        [2, 5]
(0, 'o4')    [8, 9, 12]
(0, 'o5')      [10, 13]
(0, 'o6')      [11, 14]
(0, nan)         [3, 7]
Name: x, dtype: object

df.index
Out
Index(['(0, 'o1')', '(0, 'o2')', '(0, 'o3')', '(0, 'o4')', '(0, 'o5')',
       '(0, 'o6')', '(0, nan)'],
      dtype='object')

xy_data[0].loc['(0, nan)']  # or
xy_data[0].loc[str((0, nan))]
```